# Which is the lightest way to draw images and text in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, calayer

I am planning to implement a component similar to the iphone's photo album.. I guess that using uviews will make the component to have a bad performace , I mean scrolling slow and all of the stuff ... so which way should I take?
Is CALayer better than UIViews in terms of performance? Is there any other (lighter) way
to draw images or text without using UIView subclasses?

Any link or idea will be great,

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of tutorials about graphics and the pros and cons of UIView vs drawing. I'm no expert but I suspect that performance is more likely to come from your instantiation and caching strategies. I.e. if you want fast scrolling then looking at minimising the number of objects instantiated, caching and reusing those that are and an effective block loading routine for loading data will all yield large benefits.

But I'd be inclined to do a simple proof of concept app first, load it onto a device and see how fast it goes and where you are most likely to need to address performance issues. Apart from standard design strategies such as caching and reusing components, attempting to optimize the performance before you have identified where the performance bottlenecks are occurring is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd just reinvent an existing system implementation, start by using the system's implementation and see what the specific issues are from that point.

if you've something very specialized or not easily achieved with UIView, look into CoreGraphics.framework and CoreText.framework.

much of the drawing and animation in higher level libs use the CoreGraphics technologies. however, they are often simplified or higher level and may contain specific abstraction costs. cg rendering is not for the novice - if you don't understand UIKit/AppKit rendering, you're likely to lose a lot of time learning it, and it will not necessarily be an improvement upon the UIKit/AppKit implementations. if you are very comfortable with UIView/NSView and graphics, there's a lot to gain for your customized drawing.

(i'm assuming you aren't going to the OpenGL layer with this)

it may not be a good idea to 'guess that using uiviews will make the component to have a bad performance'. if the implementation is already there, trust that Apple's spent some time optimizing it -- you will have some time to invest and potentially knowledge to acquire in the process of developing an improvement specific to your needs. i'd recommend you start with what you're already familiar with and then determine whether it needs improvement -- you can even use CG rendering within UIView/NSView so you will not necessarily need to recreate a replacement for UIView. since you didn't mention CoreGraphics in the OP, i'm guessing you're not very familiar with it.

good luck